# Pass an Razor List to Javascript (JSON)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Im tring to pass a in razor view declared list into a javascript var:

```
  List<testObj> mylist= new List<testObj>();

    <div class="listboxFilterItem" onclick=' setList(@(Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(mylist))))'> <div style="padding-top:2px; float: left;">Test</div>     <div class="listboxChosenFilter">*</div>   </div>
```

My javascript code looks like this :

```
function setList(list) {
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(list);
    console.log(jsonObj);

  }


</script>
```

But I get ILLEGAL token exception because of my quotes --> "data"<-- .

How do u pass in razor view declared lists to a javascript function?

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing onclick code.

**Replace**

```
 onclick=' setList(@(Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(mylist))))'
```

**With**

```
onclick='setList(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(mylist)))'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which MVC/.NET version you are using, but have you tried using `JavaScriptSerializer` instead of Json?

```
@{
    var myList = new List<testObj>();
    var list = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myList);
    // list now contains a JSON string repesentation of myList.
}

<script>
   var options = @Html.Raw(list);
</script>
```

The options javascript variable should then contain an array of whatever items are in the myList C# variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a strongly typed Razor cshtml view of a model with a property `ICollection<Options>`. I was looking for how to pass lists/lists of lists/list of objects into JavaScript, and saw "don't use `@Html.Raw()`" in some places for security reasons.

What worked for me in **.NET Core 3.1**, was using only `@Json.Serialize()` of the `System.Text.Json` namespace. So in my case I used it as a JavaScript variable value:

```
var myModelOptionsList = @Json.Serialize(Model.Options);
```

and now I have a list of JavaScript objects.

**Note:** The project used **EntityFramework Core** to store the model (and its Options). Each Option object had a reference navigation property back to the parent model. This caused a [JSON Self Referencing Loop Exceptions](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/03/15/fixing-json-self-referencing-loop-exceptions/) during serialization. The easiest solution was to not include these references during serialization, using `[JsonIgnore]` attribute over the model reference navigation property of the Option object.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me

```
onclick="setList('@Json.Serialize(mylist).ToString()'))"
```